# java agents with maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, aspectj

I'm running aspectjweaver as a javaagent in Eclipse. I use maven to manage my dependencies, but I need to put a path to aspectjweaver on the command line. What's the recommended way to do this? Save another copy in my workspace? Reference my local repository?

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by running on the command line, are you running the command from within Eclipse or a shell?

Comment: Rich. I was running both from Eclipse and the command line/executable jar. I ended up putting it in the repository and just referencing my local repo when running from eclipse. When I ran from the command line, the jar was in the lib folder, so it was easy to reference. I probably should've have closed this question.