# Specify javaagent argument with Maven exec plugin

Tags: maven, javaagents

I have a similar question to: [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020731/java-agents-with-maven-in-eclipse)

I am converting a Java project using Netbeans to Maven. In order to launch the program, one of the command-line arguments we need is the -javaagent setting. e.g.

```
-javaagent:lib/eclipselink.jar
```

I'm trying to get Netbeans to launch the application for development use (we will write custom launch scripts for final deployment)

Since I'm using Maven to manage the Eclipselink dependencies, I may not know the exact filename of the Eclipselink jar file. It may be something like eclipselink-2.1.1.jar based on the version I have configured in the pom.xml file.

How do I configure the exec-maven-plugin to pass the exact eclipselink filename to the command line argument?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <executable>java</executable>
           <arguments>
               <argument>-Xmx1000m</argument>
               <argument>-javaagent:lib/eclipselink.jar</argument> <==== HELP?
               <argument>-classpath</argument>
               <classpath/>
               <argument>my.App</argument>
           </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out a way that seems to work well.

First, setup the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to always run the "properties" goal.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>getClasspathFilenames</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Later on, use the property it sets [as documented here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/properties-mojo.html) with the form:

```
groupId:artifactId:type:[classifier]
```

e.g.

```
<argument>-javaagent:${mygroup:eclipselink:jar}</argument>
```

Comment: Awesomeness! I would just point out that you need to put this <plugin/> element in the very pom.xml where your <argument/> element resides. (<extraJvmArgs/> in my case)... I.e. having it in a parent pom.xml does not seem to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Simply define a property for the eclipse link version and use the property in your `<dependency>` and the exec plugin:

```
    <properties>
        <eclipselink.version>2.4.0</eclipselink.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
       <arguments>
           <argument>-Xmx1000m</argument>
           <argument>-javaagent:lib/eclipselink-${eclipselink.version}.jar</argument>
           <argument>-classpath</argument>
           <classpath/>
           <argument>my.App</argument>
       </arguments>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: Very close to what I finally chose to do. I figured out a way to set a property dynamically instead of hard-coding it. Thanks.

Comment: David, I Have the same issue, can you please share your solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

the  maven-dependency-plugin and exec-maven-plugin should be put under the node  ,otherwise it will not work